# Dynamic DataSource Configuration in DBReport/DBlookup mediator in wso2ei Esb profile

Tags: wso2-esb

In DBReport/DBLookup mediator,is it possible to pass dynamic datasource?
I want to pass datasource name from property mediator,something like this:
<property name="dsName" value="sample_dbname">
<dbreport><connection><dsName>get-property('dsName')<dsName></connection></dbreport>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi,I want to pass dynamic datasource name in dbreport mediator.I mean in dsName value should be fetched from property mediator